# Is there a way to use jquery library in all frames on the page without injecting it into all frames?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a chrome extension that needs to use jquery in all frames. So I need to inject jquery library. I am doing it currently with

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
      'file' : 'js/libs/jquery.min.js',
      'allFrames' : true
    });
```

But the thing is I have some web sites that have like 15 frames , and I do not want 15 jquery files being injected. It seems a bit too much. Is there a way to inject it only once , so other frames can use it ?

Comment: As far as I know it should be cached by the browser, so even if you reference it more than once it should only be fetched once.

Comment: 15 frames, why in the world would you need that many frames?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject jquery only on the main page and then you will be able to access jQuery inside child frames by using this code: `parent.$`

Comment: Within a Chrome extension, there's no way to reference any other `Window` instance other than the current content script's one. Your answer will not work.